# Customizing the jqgrid filter logic

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid version 4.5.2. Below is the defination of my grid. In the column model I have a column named region with the filter apply above it.

```
jq("#grid").jqGrid({       
 url:finalUrl,   
 ajaxGridOptions: {cache: false},//added the option to always reload the grid and not to cache the result.
 datatype: 'json',    
 mtype: 'GET', 
 colNames:[ 'Requestor Name'],       
 colModel:[
  {name:'requestor',index:'requestor',sortable: true, width:100,editable:false, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
  {name:'requestorRegion', index:'requestorRegion',sortable: true,width:65,editable:false, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:8, style: "height: 90%"}, stype:'select', edittype:'select',"searchoptions": {
          "value": ":All;Asia Pacific:Asia Pacific;Australia/NZ:Australia/NZ;Europe:Europe;Japan:Japan;Latin America:Latin America;North America:North America;CCEMA:CCEMA"
       }}
  ],
   postData: {     
   },    
   height: 'auto',       
   autowidth: true,    
   rownumbers: true,       
   pager: '#pager',       
   viewrecords: true,       
   sortorder: "asc",       
   emptyrecords: "Empty records",      
   loadonce: true,
   rowNum:20,
   ignoreCase: true,
   prmNames: {
       nd: null
   },   
   loadComplete: function() {
    },

   jsonReader : {    
       root: "rows",           
       repeatitems: false,
       page:"page",           
       total: "total",           
       records: "records", 
       cell: "cell",           
       id: "id"      
       }   
   });

 jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search: false, refresh:true})
   .navButtonAdd('#pager',{caption:"Export All",buttonicon:"ui-icon-document",onClickButton: function(){window.open(excelUrl,'_self');},position:"last"});
 jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn",ignoreCase: true });
```

I select the europe region from the filter than grid should filter the records accroding to the europe region.
 That is working fine. But now the requirement is that If europe region is selected then I should display all the records containing the region europe and CCEMA in the grid.Is that possible? If it is possible than how to do that ?

Note: I load all the records from the database at once in the grid using the **loadonce=true**.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly then you can try combining value for option Europe like "Europe,CCEMA:Europe;" so on server side you may receive "Europe,CCEMA" as search value when you select Europe in dropdown. Then you can use these values with SQL "in" clause with little modification.

you can also use character other than comma (,) to combine different values but you will have to set the logic accordingly on server side.

give this a try see if it helps

e.g.

```
    {name:'requestorRegion', index:'requestorRegion',sortable: true,width:65,editable:false, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:8, style: "height: 90%"}, stype:'select', edittype:'select',"searchoptions": {
      "value": ":All;Asia Pacific:Asia Pacific;Australia/NZ:Australia/NZ;Europe,CCEMA:Europe;Japan:Japan;Latin America:Latin America;North America:North America;CCEMA:CCEMA"
   }}
```